# Hide Title Bar in Service.Is it possible?

Tags: android

I want to hide title bar in `Service` without using `Activity`.Can I somehow do so?I thought it might work with `requestWindowFeature` and `NO_TITLE_FEATURE` but android studio says that it can't resolve this method.May be somebody can help me?

Comment: `Service` have no UI. So there is no `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the title bar is part of the Activity. Therefore the Activity must control what window features it uses or doesn't use.